# Ruby on Rails on BigData

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdata

I am newbie in `BigData` `Hadoop` and `Rails` but I want to create an `rails application` on using `Bigdata`....can anyone suggest me any helpful link or documentation....by which I can start an application of Rails using `BigData`.....

One Help I get after googling http://quickleft.com/blog/handling-the-headaches-of-big-data-with-rails  but it is not implemented any application ....

So any kind of help will be appreciable ....
thanks in advance

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HDFS storage framework, you can create a module using HDFS REST API wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HDFS-APIs.